# pythonic way of raising an error within the try block

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have a method that checks something and which can

- raise an exception itself
- return True
- return False

I want catch the exception properly to raise one myself, but also if the test returns False. The incorrect way to do this is

```
try:
    if not check():
        raise MyException()
except:
    raise MyException()
```

as the first `MyException` is caught after the `except` again. One way to handle this properly would be

```
try:
    flag = check()
except:
    raise MyException()
else:
    if not flag:
        raise MyException()
```

Is this the only way of dealing with this situation, or is there another way to handle it more efficient, getting rid of the `flag` variable?

Comment: First of all: don't use blanket `except:` catching, always only catch *specific* exceptions.

Comment: @avasal: what makes you think the OP doesn't know about `raise`?

Comment: You should add what Exception is raised in check(), because as you can see from the answers: there are a few ways to do this.

Comment: yes, always except for a specific exception in the normal case. But when you run something on a server, you don't want the server stop because of an error, you want to propagate ANY error to the client.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should never use except: because that catches ALL exceptions, including SystemExit, you should probably do:

```
try:
    if not check():
        raise MyNewException()
except ExceptionRaisedByCheck:
    raise MyNewException()
```

If the exception coming from check() is the same as the one you want to raise, you should change that.

Edit: If the exception is the same, you can also simply do this (Mark Byers had this in his answer, but it's gone now):

```
if not check():
    raise TheSameException()
```

This will propagate the exception or raise if False.

Comment: +1 this doesn't strictly answer the question, but IMHO the question is just not really thought out very well. This is almost certainly better than whatever the OP mistakenly assumed was a good idea, though without some more background it's hard to tell what he's trying to do.

Comment: @MarkByers you deleted your answer? I edited mine to add part of your answer because that was really the simplest solution and I didn't think about it before. As you said, hard to tell what the objective is.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
   # whatever
except MyException:
   raise # reraise it
except Exception as e:
   raise MyException(some_info(e)) # unify user-visible exception type
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.3, you can use the new [`contextlib.ExitStack` context manager](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack):

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    stack.callback(lambda: raise MyException)

    if check():
        stack.pop_all()
```

This will raise `MyException`, *unless* you clear the stack callbacks with `pop_all()`.

You can codify this is into a custom context manager:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

class ExceptionUnlessCancelled(ExitStack):
    def __init__(self, exception, *args, **kw):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.exception = exception
        self.callback(self.raiseException, *args, **kwds)

    def raiseException(self, *args, **kw):
        raise self.exception(*args, **kw)

    def cancel(self):
        self.pop_all()

with ExceptionUnlessCancelled(MyException) as exc:
    if check():
        exc.cancel()
```

Comment: Seems a little over-engineered, but still, interesting solution!

Comment: @SebastianBlask: I think context managers are great ways of dealing with complex exception situations. The OP's situation has been simplified for the question, who knows how much more code surrounds the check?